# While gvim is running, mintty displays Unicode UTF-8 characters as question marks

Tags: windows-10, cygwin, gvim, mintty

When I fire up *gvim* in the background in a Cygwin *mintty* terminal, Unicode UTF-8 characters start getting displayed as question marks. When I quit *gvim*, *mintty* reverts to the correct behaviour.  In addition, the bold parts of *man* page output rendered as color also disappear when *gvim* is invoked in the background.  Running `reset` doesn't fix the problem. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
$ echo -e "\xce\xbb\x0a"
λ

$ '/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/vim/vim82/gvim' &
[1] 8340
$ echo -e "\xce\xbb\x0a"
?

$ wait # Quit gvim
[1]+  Done                    '/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/vim/vim82/gvim'
$ echo -e "\xce\xbb\x0a"
λ

$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-10.0 dell 3.1.5(0.340/5/3) 2020-06-01 08:59 x86_64 Cygwin
$ gvim --version # Opens dialog window showing:
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Dec 15 2019 23:09:16)
MS-Windows 32-bit GUI version with OLE support
Included patches: 1-12
Compiled by appveyor@APPVYR-WIN
```

Comment: is that gvim using a cygwin1.dll under the hood ? Have you tried to run it though a CMD session ?

Comment: The gvim I run doesn't import cygwin: `dumpbin /imports "$(cygpath -w "$(which gvim)")" | grep -i cygwin`. The problem doesn't occur when running gvim from other (mintty or cmd) windows. It does also occur when running gvim under cmd from the mintty window: `cmd /c gvim &`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting *gvim* in the background within a sub-shell avoids the problem.

```
$ echo -e "\xce\xbb\x0a"
λ

$ (gvim &)
$ echo -e "\xce\xbb\x0a"
λ
```